# New Super Luigi U not starting

Tags: new-super-luigi-u

I recently bought both New Super Mario Bros U and New Super Luigi U on disc for the Wii U. I have my NSMBU fully updated and when I take out the disc and put in the NSLU disc, I get stuck on the loading screen. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd check is your disc for scratches or smudges. Games will typically freeze/hang when it can't read certain spots on the disc.

The next thing I'd recommend trying is to delete local storage for both games and try launching the game again.